# Why does the shape operator (Weingarten map) exist?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, surfaces, implicit-function-theorem

**Preliminaries/Notation:** Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be open, and let $(f^1, f^2, f^3)=f: U \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular parametrization/surface (i.e. immersion). Let $p \in U$ be given. Then there exists a neighborhood $V \subset U$ of $p$ such that $f|_V$ is an embedding and thus $f(V)$ is diffeomorphic to $V$. Let $(x_1, x_2)$ be the coordinate system for $U$. Finally, let $(N^1, N^2, N^3)=N: U \to \mathbb{S}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the unit normal vector field for $f$, $N(p)=\frac{f_{x_1} \times f_{x_2}}{|| f_{x_1} \times f_{x_2}||}$.

**Definition of Weingarten Operator:** The definition of Weingarten operator I have is as follows: for any $(p, (v_1, v_2)) = v \in T_p V$, the Weingarten operator is the function $A: T_p V \to T_p V$ such that for $(p, (w_1,w_2))=w:=AV \in T_p V$, one has $$Df(p)(w) = \nabla_v N(p)$$ where $Df(p)(w)=(f(p), ( f^1_{x_1}w_1 + f^1_{x_2}w_2, f^2_{x_1}w_1 + f^2_{x_2}w_2, f^3_{x_1}w_1 + f^3_{x_2}w_2)  )$ and $\nabla_v N(p) = (f(p),(N^1_{x_1}v_1 + N^1_{x_2}v_2, N^2_{x_1}v_1 + N^2_{x_2}v_2, N^3_{x_1}v_1 + N^3_{x_2}v_2)) $. I am aware that this definition differs by a minus sign from the typical one, and also that $\nabla_v N(p) \perp N(p)$ is what guarantees us the necessary but not sufficient condition for $A$ to be well-defined that $\nabla_v N(p) \in T_{f(p)}f(V)$.

> Obviously what we really need for $A$ to be well-defined is that $w$ exists and is unique. The above definition leads to following system of linear equations: $$\begin{bmatrix} N^1_{x_1} & N^1_{x_2} \\ N^2_{x_1} & N^2_{x_2} \\ N^3_{x_1} & N^3_{x_2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} f^1_{x_1} & f^1_{x_2} \\ f^2_{x_1} & f^2_{x_2} \\ f^3_{x_1} & f^3_{x_2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} w_1 \\ w_2 \end{bmatrix} $$ Therefore the question of the well-definedness of $A$ reduces to multivariable calculus.
>
> **My question:** How can we use the implicit function theorem to show that a solution for this system of equations always exists, and that it must be unique?
>
> That $f$ is an immersion and therefore $Df(p)$ has rank $2$ must surely be relevant somehow.
>
> **a.** How does the implicit function theorem allow us to conclude that there exists a change of coordinates such that $DN(p)$ can be written as a $2 \times 2$ matrix? (Since $\mathbb{S}^2$ is a 2-manifold.)
>
> **b.** Does the exact same reasoning as for **1.** allow us to write $Df(p)$ as a $2 \times 2$ matrix? (Since $f$ also maps $U$ to a 2-manifold?)
>
> **c.** Since $f$ and $N$ are different (albeit related) functions, how can we ensure that there is a coordinate system which satisfies both **1.** and **2.**? (I think the answer might have something to do with "normal coordinates", but I don't understand Riemannian geometry, so I can't tell.)

---

**Note:** A very similar question has been asked here before, but the answer given seems incorrect. [Matrix representation of shape operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120454/matrix-representation-of-shape-operator). The reason why is that, at least with the definition of unit normal vector field which I have, $DN$ should be a $3 \times 2$ matrix, because it maps a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$, which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Also, even if the given answer is correct, I am still unsatisfied with it, because it must be using somewhere the assumption that the given parametrization of the surface is an immersion, i.e. a regular parametrization/regular surface, but I don't see where.

I am aware that the proof of the Weingarten equations most likely answers my question; however, I want to use the answer to my question to prove the Weingarten equations. Specifically, I want to be able to use the implicit function theorem to get from questions about $3 \times 2$ matrices to questions about invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices, rather than hide the implicit function theorem "under the rug".

---

This is a follow-up to three of my previous questions:

[What is the dimension of a tangent space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879590/what-is-the-dimension-of-a-tangent-space/1880172?noredirect=1#comment3855110_1880172)
[Motivation behind notation for tangent space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879301/motivation-behind-notation-for-tangent-space)
[Why is the image of the implicit function in the implicit function theorem not open?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1750215/why-is-the-image-of-the-implicit-function-in-the-implicit-function-theorem-not-o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear system of equations so there is no need to invoke the implicit function theorem, only basic linear algebra. Denote by $N_{x_i} = \begin{pmatrix} N^1_{x_i} \\ N^2_{x_i} \\ N^3_{x_i} \end{pmatrix}$. Since $(Df)(p)$ has rank two, the columns $f_{x_1}(p),f_{x_2}(p)$ are linearly independent and span a two dimensional plane whose normal vector is $N(p)$. Differentiating $\left< N, N \right> = 1$ with respect to $x_i$, we see that $\left< N_{x_i}, N \right> = 0$ so $N_{x_i} \in N^{\perp} = \operatorname{span}(f_{x_1}, f_{x_2})$. Hence, given $v_1,v_2$, the vector $v_1 N_{x_1} +  v_2 N_{x_2}$ belongs to $\operatorname{span}(f_{x_1}, f_{x_2})$ and so can be written uniquely as a linear combination

$$ v_1 N_{x_1} +  v_2 N_{x_2} = w_1 f_{x_1} + w_2 f_{x_2} $$

which is precisely your matrix equation.

Comment: Haha thank you so much! This is much easier than I had realized.